# WCF webHttpBinding post to apache service

Tags: wcf, apache, wcf-client, webhttpbinding

I am trying to communicate with an Apache service from a WCF client

I have set up the client like this:

```
<client>
    <endpoint name="ApacheService" 
              address="SomeUrl" 
              behaviorConfiguration="ApacheBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="ISomeContrect" />
</client>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ApacheBehavior">
            <webHttp />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and my contract looks like

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post, 
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               UriTemplate = "?user={username}&action=someaction")]
    void dosomeaction(string username, List<SomeJSONSerializableObject> data);
```

Don't know what framework is used on the receiving side but the user and action variables are presented as get variables and the json payload is not seen at all.

```
debug started
post:
Array
(
)
get:
Array
(
    [user] => someusername
    [action] => someaction
)
json:
```

I did some local tests with a WCF service and it works fine.

Any ideas what ca be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It was some error on the Apache side